# How to use VBA to categorize data and transfer to other file?

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a shop selling snacks. There are totally 50 snack brands (brand A, brand B, brand C ...... ) and I have to submit the weekly sale reports to 50 different brand suppliers.

Firstly I have an original excel file that contain the daily transactions. (not yet categorized by brand) Let say the column A is "Brand" and the following columns are the brand detail such as price and profit.

Since each brand's total sale is confidence, I have to separate the transactions into 50 different files based on its brand and submit separately. It takes time to do so manually so I am thinking about using the VBA code.

I guess, I will do the following

1. Create 50 excel files and name them according to the brand.
2. In the original file, test if the first cell of each row (brand) matches the name of the destination file. If yes, copy that cell and the next right two cells (profit and price) and paste to the destination file. If no, skip that row.
3. Repeat such actions until complete transferring data for brand A
4. Do it for brand B, brand C and so on until finish 50 brands.

The problem is that I am new to VBA so I don't know how to begin with.

1. How many VBA workbook do I need to create?
2. How to construct the if function for the "brand" cell to see if it matches the destination file.
3. Can I use VBA code to create 50 excel workbooks all at once?
4. When I copy the cells, how can I past it to the next empty row of the destination file?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried following your manual process with the Macro Recorder enabled? That might get you quite a bit down the road toward a full VBA solution. As it stands, this question is a bit broad (we tend to prefer users do at least some of the legwork & research for their question/problem before asking here.

Comment: I would restructure your logic. **First:** Find out how many unique brands you have. Then create that many new sheets with the `Sheet Name = Brand`. **Second:** Loop through sheets and filter your main sheet by Brand and `Copy/Paste Visible Cells`. **Last:** Save each worksheet as it's own workbook. I would do steps 1 & 2 in the same macro. Then your 3rd macro as it's own

Answer (score 0):

I am essentially dumping pre-existing code that I already have here for you to use. Since this is way more than your question deserves (*given you have no code to share on a code-assistance site*), I will not make any edits to this.

I will leave that to you - try to understand what the code is doing and bend it to fit your needs when needed

---

### The macro....

1. Determines unique list of values as determined by `Column A`
2. Creates a new sheet for each unique value such that `Sheet Name = Unique Value`
3. Loops through each new sheet filtering the raw data by the sheet name (unique identifier) and copies/pastes all filtered cells to their respective sheets
4. The next macro (needs to be called separately) will create a new folder wherever the master book is saved & then begin saving each sheet as it's own workbook.

---

### Create unique sheet for each unique Brand

```
Sub parse_data()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant

Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = 1

lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row

titlerow = ws.Range("A1").Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

For i = 2 To lr
On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
Next

myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear

For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range("A1:C" & lr).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
    ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit

Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate

End Sub
```

### Create unique book for each sheet created above

```
' New MACRO

Sub SplitWorkbook()
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & "Brands" & DateString
MkDir FolderName
For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        Select Case xWb.FileFormat
            Case 51:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56:
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
    End If



    xFile = FolderName & "\" & "Brands" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

*I wrote this a year ago and have had no issues using it, although looking at the code again, I can spot updates that can be made.*